# In the vim plugin script, how to get the path of the file?

Tags: vim

I am writing a vim plugin, how can i get the absolute path according to an file?

for example,

```
let s:file="/home/ABC/ABC.txt"
```

how to get the path string `/home/ABC`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fnamemodify()` function:

```
let s:dir = fnamemodify(s:file, ":p:h")
```

See `:help fnamemodify()` for details on that function.

See `:help filename-modiers` for the meaning of `:p:h`.

See `:help file-functions` for a list of file-related functions and hit `<C-]>` on a function name to jump to its documentation. You can do the same for `list-functions`, `buffer-functions` and so on. Handy, isn't it?

Comment: Also see `:help <sfile>` and `:help expand()` if you want the file name and path of the currently executing script.